# directly start Activity if user has already registered

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I am new in android development. i want my application to directly launch MainActivity if the User has already registered. how can i do this.
this is my MainActivity

```
  public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private Toolbar toolbar;
Button btnTip, btnApp, btndos, btnAbout, btnServices;
ConnectionDetector cd;
AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> mRegisterTask;
public static String name;
public static String email;
public static String contact;
public static String imei;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
    toolbar.setTitle("Dental Application");
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    btnTip = (Button) findViewById(R.id.tips);
    btndos = (Button) findViewById(R.id.dos);
    btnApp = (Button) findViewById(R.id.appointments);
    btnAbout = (Button) findViewById(R.id.about);
    btnServices = (Button) findViewById(R.id.services);
    // Alert dialog manager
    AlertDialogManager alert = new AlertDialogManager();
    cd = new ConnectionDetector(getApplicationContext());

    // Check if Internet present
    if (!cd.isConnectingToInternet()) {
        // Internet Connection is not present
        alert.showAlertDialog(MainActivity.this,
                "Internet Connection Error",
                "Please check your Internet connection", false);
        // stop executing code by return
        return;
    }

    Intent i = getIntent();

    name = i.getStringExtra("name");
    email = i.getStringExtra("email");
    contact = i.getStringExtra("contact");
    imei = i.getStringExtra("imei");
    // Make sure the device has the proper dependencies.
    GCMRegistrar.checkDevice(this);

    // Make sure the manifest was properly set - comment out this line
    // while developing the app, then uncomment it when it's ready.
    GCMRegistrar.checkManifest(this);

    //lblMessage = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblMessage);

    registerReceiver(mHandleMessageReceiver, new IntentFilter(
            DISPLAY_MESSAGE_ACTION));

    // Get GCM registration id
    final String regId = GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(this);

    // Check if regid already presents
    if (regId.equals("")) {
        // Registration is not present, register now with GCM
        GCMRegistrar.register(this, SENDER_ID);
    } else {
        // Device is already registered on GCM
        if (GCMRegistrar.isRegisteredOnServer(this)) {
            // Skips registration.
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Already registered with GCM", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            // Try to register again, but not in the UI thread.
            // It's also necessary to cancel the thread onDestroy(),
            // hence the use of AsyncTask instead of a raw thread.
            final Context context = this;
            mRegisterTask = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {

                @Override
                protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                    // Register on our server
                    // On server creates a new user
                    ServerUtilities.register(context, name, email, regId, contact, imei);
                    return null;
                }

                @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
                    mRegisterTask = null;
                }

            };
            mRegisterTask.execute(null, null, null);
        }
    }

    btnTip.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, TipsActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    btndos.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DosActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    btnApp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, BookAppointmennts.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    btnAbout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AboutUsActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    btnServices.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ServicesActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            finish();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

/**
 * Receiving push messages
 * */
private final BroadcastReceiver mHandleMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String newMessage = intent.getExtras().getString(EXTRA_MESSAGE);
        // Waking up mobile if it is sleeping
        WakeLocker.acquire(getApplicationContext());

        /**
         * Take appropriate action on this message
         * depending upon your app requirement
         * For now i am just displaying it on the screen
         * */

        // Showing received message
        //lblMessage.append(newMessage + "\n");
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "New Message: " + newMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        // Releasing wake lock
        WakeLocker.release();
    }
};

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    if (mRegisterTask != null) {
        mRegisterTask.cancel(true);
    }
    try {
        unregisterReceiver(mHandleMessageReceiver);
        GCMRegistrar.onDestroy(this);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("UnRegister Receiver", "> " + e.getMessage());
    }
    super.onDestroy();
}

}
```

and the RegisterActivity

```
  public class RegisterActivity extends Activity {
// alert dialog manager
AlertDialogManager alert = new AlertDialogManager();

// Internet detector
ConnectionDetector cd;

// UI elements
EditText txtName;
EditText txtEmail;
EditText txtContact;

// Register button
Button btnRegister;
String imei;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);


    cd = new ConnectionDetector(getApplicationContext());

    // Check if Internet present
    if (!cd.isConnectingToInternet()) {
        // Internet Connection is not present
        alert.showAlertDialog(RegisterActivity.this,
                "Internet Connection Error",
                "Please connect to working Internet connection", false);
        // stop executing code by return
        return;
    }

    // Check if GCM configuration is set
    if (SERVER_URL == null || SENDER_ID == null || SERVER_URL.length() == 0
            || SENDER_ID.length() == 0) {
        // GCM sernder id / server url is missing
        alert.showAlertDialog(RegisterActivity.this, "Configuration Error!",
                "Please set your Server URL and GCM Sender ID", false);
        // stop executing code by return
        return;
    }

    txtName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtName);
    txtEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtEmail);
    txtContact = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.contact);
    btnRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnRegister);
    TelephonyManager mngr = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    imei = mngr.getDeviceId();
    /*
     * Click event on Register button
     * */
    btnRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // Read EditText dat
            String name = txtName.getText().toString();
            String email = txtEmail.getText().toString();
            String contact = txtContact.getText().toString();
            // Check if user filled the form
            if (name.trim().length() > 0 && email.trim().length() > 0 && contact.trim().length()>0) {
                // Launch Main Activity
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);

                // Registering user on our server
                // Sending registraiton details to MainActivity
                i.putExtra("name", name);
                i.putExtra("email", email);
                i.putExtra("contact", contact);
                i.putExtra("imei", imei);
                startActivity(i);
                finish();
            } else {
                // user doen't filled that data
                // ask him to fill the form
                alert.showAlertDialog(RegisterActivity.this, "Registration Error!", "Please enter your details", false);
            }
        }
    });
}

 }
```

i am using GCM. the user is first registered and MainActivity is Displayed. Next time when the user opens the application i want directly MainActivity to be displayed. how can i do this. Can anyone please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to make LauncherActivity like SplashScreen in which check from shared prefrences or sqlite data that user is already registered or not
then by checking this transfer to corresponding activity.

If the user is not registered then show Registration Screen and when user register then save info in Sqlite or sharedpreferences or any other way.

If the user is already registered the show HomeScreen

Answer (score 0):

First of all just post only the code that needs modification,  you've posted all of the code in that Java file of yours.  We could be more helpful if your code isn't cluttered.